# Python installation error no matching distribution found for pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run this program

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

plt.plot([1, 2, 3],[5, 7, 4])
plt.show()
```

I am getting an error message:
ImportError: No module named pyplot

I have installed matplotlib on Windows 8 64-bit, Python 2.7 with pip command from bash and I also updated it, got this message as a result:

```
Aneta@AKZ-5K-Computer:~$ C:/Python27/Scripts/pip install --upgrade matplotlib
Requirement already up-to-date: matplotlib in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pyparsing>=1.5.6 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing-2.0.3-py2.7-win32.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.6 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2015.6-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.4 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
```

When I tried to install pyplot I got this massage:

```
Aneta@AKZ-5K-Computer:~$ C:/Python27/Scripts/pip install pyplot
Collecting pyplot
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyplot (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyplot
```

If anyone has an idea how to install pyplot and why my distribution is not matching, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I install matplotlib from a wheel file, as on Windows I've never been able to successfully install the 64 bit version from pip.  So try downloading the .whl file and installing from that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try reinstalling matplotlib from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib). It doesn't matter if you're on a 64 bit computer (I am as well). What matters is which version of Python did you install? If you installed the 32-bit (recommended as it's somewhat easier to deal with), then you still install the 32-bit versions of modules.

The site I linked you shows prerequisite modules for matplotlib, so make sure you also have those installed.

Answer (score 10):

If you try

```
pip install matplotlib
```

and it fails, try

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

You might already have the package pre-installed.

Answer (score 9):

Or what you can do is just try 
    `pip install matplotlib`.
Then import matplotlib.pyplot to make get the pyplot data. matplotlib is a module with pyplot inside it so you can access pyplot easily.

Comment: This is the main point: `pip install matplotlib` so that you can `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` or `import pylab`